# Loops and row references

Tags: excel, vba

The below code needs to run the =disvincenty formula on a loop, and the referenced cells $C$2,$D$2 need to go down one row each time in same column each time code block runs until ABF (Last row with data in column T.) then it exit's sub

For each row, it needs to run the formulas =Min and the two =small's in the same columns already referenced, but also dropping down one row at a time - the same as the =distvincenty, but values being pasted each time to preserve result.

So =distvincenty is looking at two criteria in cells next to each other on same row, compares to a list running down a column, applies the three other formulas to that row, and moves down.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ABF As Integer
ABF = Sheet9.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set rng = Range("Q2:Q" & ABF)

For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells


        Sheet9.Range("Q2").Formula = "=distVincenty($C$2,$D$2,$R2,$S2)/1609.344"
        Sheet9.Range("Q2").Copy
        Sheet9.Range("Q2:Q" & ABF).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Sheet9.Range("E2").Formula = "=MIN(Q:Q)"
        Sheet9.Range("H2").Formula = "=SMALL(Q:Q,2)"
        Sheet9.Range("K2").Formula = "=SMALL(Q:Q,3)"

    Next cell
Next row
```

**UPDATE:**

I now have this:

```
Dim ABF As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Sheet9.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  ABF = Sheet10.Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


    Sheet10.Range("AE3").Formula = "=distVincenty('Booking Workings'!$C$2,'Booking Workings'!$D$2,'User List'!$Z3,'User List'!$AA3)/1609.344"
    Sheet10.Range("AE3").Copy
    Sheet10.Range("AE3:AE" & ABF).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
       Application.CutCopyMode = False


    Sheet9.Range("E" & i).Formula = "=MIN('User List'!AE:AE)"
    Sheet9.Range("H" & i).Formula = "=SMALL('User List'!AE:AE,2)"
    Sheet9.Range("K" & i).Formula = "=SMALL('User List'!AE:AE,3)"

   Next i    

End sub
```

The only problem I have is that each time this code runs, I need the $C$2 and $D$2 to change like the simpler formulas.

Can I do this?

```
        Sheet10.Range("AE3").Formula = "=distVincenty('Booking Workings'!$C$"(I)",'Booking Workings'!$D$"(I)",'User List'!$Z3,'User List'!$AA3)/1609.344"
```

**UPDATE**
looks like this works:

```
"=distVincenty('Booking Workings'!$C$" & (i) & ",'Booking Workings'!$D$" & (i) & ",'User List'!$Z3,'User List'!$AA3)/1609.344"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to explain.  Let me know if I'm close.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ABF As Integer
    Dim arrValues
    Dim count As Integer

    ABF = Sheet9.Range("T" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = Range("Q2:Q" & ABF)
    arrValues = rng.Value

    For Each cell In rng

        Sheet9.Range("Q2:Q" & ABF).Formula = "=distVincenty($C$" & cell.row & ",$D$" & cell.row & ",$R2,$S2)/1609.344"

        Sheet9.Range("E2").Formula = "=MIN(Q:Q)"
        Sheet9.Range("H2").Formula = "=SMALL(Q:Q,2)"
        Sheet9.Range("K2").Formula = "=SMALL(Q:Q,3)"

        count = count + 1
        arrValues(count) = cell.Value
    Next cell

    Sheet9.Range("Q2:Q" & ABF).Value = arrValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, the $C$2, $D$2 need to be locked to those cells, so then the criteria is match to two other cells moving down the column Q. Min & small 1 & 2 then record the results, and then the formula runs again, with the two locked cell refs moving down just one row - as well as the min and small 1&2. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe if I ran the code on the list in a separate sheet, then once it analyses the co ordinates, it deletes the row and runs again etc. Would that be a work around?

Comment: So you don't want to add a formula to the cells in `"Q2:Q" & ABF` only the values.

Comment: $C$2 $D$2 = Latitude and longitude. Column Q references latitude and longitude in a list, and tells you how many miles away each person in a list is from a location. Then the Smalls and min tell you who the closest three people are, records this. Process repeats with the locked Cells moving to $C$3 $D$3 and process repeats until you get to the end of list,

Comment: If `cell.row = 2` then  `=distVincenty($C$2,$D$2",$R2,$S2)/1609.344` and if If `cell.row = 3` then  `=distVincenty($C$3,$D$3",$R2,$S2)/1609.344`?

Comment: Hi Thomas, The problem is this code will have to analyse hundreds of rows.

Comment: I save all the values in arrValues and paste them back to Column Q after the code has ran.  A few hundred rows is no problem.  I'm just not sure that I understand what you are doing.  Is `distVincenty` query Google Maps and calculating the distance between coordinates?

Comment: I have VBA code that uses the Vincenty formula to measure the distance between two set of co ordinates. I am building an automated document that tells people who is closest to a location. I think I have figured it out now. Thanks for your help on this